# Amazon EC2 Laravel app not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel, laravel-4, http-status-code-404

So I was able to put my Laravel app onto an amazon ec2 and was able to ssh and upload my files properly. The problem comes when I try to access any other links besides my '/' route (or my main index page). I thought maybe my files did not upload properly and so I tried to test accessing other routes with the standard Laravel framework.

My Routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');

Route::get('/test', 'HomeController@testFunction');
```

My Home Controller:

```
    public function showWelcome()
    {
            return 'hello';
    }

    public function testFunction()
    {
            return 'test';
    }
```

When I am accessing my website via the given ec2 dns domain: http://ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, the main page shows, meaning that I am getting a page that just says 'hello'. However when i put in http://ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/test I am getting a 404 NOT FOUND error.

I have tried looking around online but I could not find something similar to my issue. Please help me out and Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am receiving this same error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set below permission in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Add this to end of the 000-default.conf:

AllowOverride All

run this as root user:
1. sudo a2enmod rewrite
2. service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ec2 has something to do with this issue. Try this. `Route::get('test', 'HomeController@testFunction');` You don't have to put `/` in routes except for the root.

Further reading
http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers